# How can i get the list of images url's in twig template, Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a content type with image field limited to 10 images. I need to get the list of url's to create a slider in the template. I'm able to access the first url using the below code.

```
{{ file_url(content.field_banner_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

How can i get the full list of images respective to each node? I need my template to be populated as below

```
<ul>
   <li>imageUrl 1</li>
   <li>imageUrl 2</li>
   <li>imageUrl 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: https://www.drupal.org/project/slick

The advantage with this module is that it's already responsive and comes with a lot of features and configuration options.

As a general tip: whenever you think about coding something very common (image slider/gallery) yourself, research if there's already a module for that, because chances are there is! You don't need to re-invent the wheel ;-)

But anyway, how to get the urls of a multi-value image field? Like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in content.field_banner_image['#items'] %}
    <li>{{ file_url(item.entity.uri.value) }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Slider is just an example. I'm new to Drupal but I'm pretty good at frontend. So if I can get these details to frontend, I can easily tweak as required :)